# How can I know when a row has been added to a WPF4 DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid

I have bound a WPF4 DataGrid to an ObervableCollection in the conventional way. I can add to the collection and get a new row in my grid. All good. But, how can I know when the new row has been added and I can do something with it? I want to set the focus to a particular cell in the new row and make it editable. There seems to be no event along the lines of "NewRowAddedAndYouCanDoSomethingWithIt".

Edit 11:39 4 Dec:
Thanks all for your reponses. Despite the lectures on what to do or not I'm still puzzling about how to achieve this. I add to the ObervableCollection and get a new row that the user can edit but I want to avoid the user needing to click in the new row. I want the cursor in a specific cell in edit mode once a new row is added in the DataGrid.

Comment: i use the datagrid in mvvm manner. so i set UserCanAddRows=false, but give the user a button to a "new row". within this buttoncommand i add a new item to my source collection.

Comment: Indeed, but how do you know when the row has been added to the DataGrid?

Comment: you dont need to know this because if you bind the itemssource to a oberservablecollection then you know as far as you add a new item to your collection a new row to the datagrid its been added.

Comment: Yes, but it isn't added immediately. You can't on one line of code add to the ObervableCollection and then on the next line access the new row in the DataGrid because it isn't there yet.

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing the UI row element in code behind anyway... there's no need to do that.

Comment: I don't really care how it's done, but I want a specific cell of the newly created row to have the cursor ready for editing.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a strange question... you say that you *bound a WPF4 DataGrid to an ObervableCollection in the conventional way* and that you can *add to the collection and get a new row in my grid*. But your question is *How can I know when a row has been added?*

You can know when a row has been added... because when you add an item to the collection... the Framework will add a row to the `DataGrid`.

Furthermore, if you really were using MVVM correctly, then you wouldn't care when the UI row is actually added, because when using WPF and MVVM, we manipulate data, not UI elements. In that case, you would bind some `bool` property to the `IsFocused` property and set it from your view model instead.

Comment: To do something to the newly added row in the DataGrid I need to know when it has been created. I'd like there to be an event which is fired when a row has been added that ca be bound to a command.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the answer and comments:

if you add a new row to your collection

```
 var myNewRow = new MyObject(){Name="its New"};
 this.MyCollection.Add(myNewRow);//<-- this new row is added to you collection, and your datagrid will show the new row

 myNewRow.Name = "Test1";//if you implment INotifyPropertyChanged in your MyObject, the new Value its displayed in the grid
```

you never need an event when the new row is added to the grid in this case. but maybe i miss something, so let my know if you have other requirements.

Comment: I want a specific cell of the newly created row to have the cursor ready for editing.